# Cell in XtraGrid and chaging Background Color?

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress, xtragrid

I have one DataTable with three columns and five rows.
The DataTable will add it to one of DevExpress XtraGrid.
I would like to change the background color of the cell (3, 3) of the grid or in the same DataTable if possible.

regards
alex

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the CustomDrawCell event on GridView.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic